# Importing a custom package from DevOps in Unity UPM

Tags: unity-game-engine, azure-devops, package-managers

I'm working on a project that is hosted on the company's DevOps; since most project share the same basic functionalities, I've created a git submodule that gets imported into every project. However, I'm looking to migrate this to Unity's package manager, so that it is easier to manage.

I've created a project [as explained in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mgsLb3TKljk), but whenever I try to import the package by adding the git url I get this error:

[image: Error in importing through HTTPS]

How can I import a custom pkg from AzDO?

I tried importing through DevOps Clone command:

[image: Devops HTTPS]

I also tried setting up a SSH mode, but Unity displays an error message saying that it expects a password, but I don't know which password SSH expects (it's not the one I setup while generating SSH keys, nor is it the one associated to the DevOps account, so I'm at a loss).

Comment: as i dont recall any method of specifying ssh keys in unity, my first guess is its not using the keys but trying to login as you as a user (your server should be able to confirm that).  as for https - i think it needs to end in .git

Comment: @BugFinder is there a way to get the .git link from DevOps?

Comment: i dont use devops myself sorry

Comment: Hi there, Good to know the issue is resolved. Would you accept your answer which may help others with similar concerns. Thx.

Comment: Sure! Thanks for having remided me of it, I forgot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to do it...but via SSH. I'm going to write the whole procedure for all the people that are as ignorant as me in this matter;

Making the package is the easy part, and explained fully in the video in the first post I made;

Next step is generating SSH keys.

Open up shell or Powershell and run:
Code (CSharp):

```
ssh-keygen
```

It will prompt you for a location where to save private and public keys; default name is id_rsa. Don't change it, just press Enter.
IMPORTANT keygen process will prompt you for a password. DO NOT insert the password, otherwise Unity won't be able to logon later.
When all is done you will have generated two files:

```
id_rsa
id_rsa.pub
```

At the following path:
Code (CSharp):

```
C:\Users\<your-user-name>\.ssh
```

Next, open up DevOps and go to the "Clone" tab in your Repo. Select "SSH" and then "Manage SSH Keys"
[image: upload_2023-11-20_16-38-15.png]
Click on "New Key" and in the Public Key Data field copy the contents of the id_rsa.pub you've generated earlier.
Save, and now go to Unity.
Take the SSH clone link you've copied earlier, and just add it to UPM as url:
[image: upload_2023-11-20_16-42-20.png]
There you go. You're done. Took me forever to figure out this simple thing.